# Add different annotations/shapes to subplots in PlotlyJS

Tags: julia, plotly.js

I want to plot two line plots in using PlotlyJS together in a subplot. One of them has shapes and annotations but when I plot them together, the shapes/annotations disappear. When I try to add it after doing the subplot (either by relayout!() or using p.plot.layout["shapes"]), it is added to both of the plots. Does anyone know how to get around this issue?

In the simple example below, p2 has the shape (vertical line) but p does not and when you add it later, it's added to both graphs as expected.

```
p1 = plot(scatter(;x = 1:10, y = 1:10));
p2 = plot(scatter(;x = 1:20, y = 1:20), Layout(shapes = vline([5], line_dash = "dot")));
p = [p1;p2];
p.plot.layout["shapes"] = vline([5], line_dash = "dot")
```

Best,

Comment: Having a minimum working example would help getting your question answered more quickly: See https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Comment: Thanks! Updated.

Comment: `Unknown key: line_dash`. What version of julia and Plots package are you using?

Comment: Hi @FelipeLema I saw this quite late. I'm using PlotlyJS.jl v.0.10.2 (not Plots.jl) and Julia v0.6.4. Should probably update I know but we're a having issues with compliance between different versions so currently have to stick with 0.6.4.